# Create a method in an eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models. One is `Order` and the other is `Item`. An order can have many items, and an item can have only one order.

I have this inside of my Order model:

```
public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'OrderNumber', 'OrderNumber');
}
```

And here's my Item model:

```
function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

I'd like to have a function that can get the total of all of the items for an order. For example, I want to be able to use `$order->items->totalPrice()` to retrieve the total.

I've tried adding this to the Item model, with no luck.

```
public function totalPrice() {

    $total = 0;

    foreach($this as $item) {
        $total += $item->AmountPaid;
    }

    return $total;

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$totalPrice
```

What is the best/cleanest way to do what I'm trying to achieve? Even better, does Laravel have a built in method for totalling up?

Comment: `$order->items` is a `Collection` not an instance of a `Item` model... loading a `hasMany` relationship always returns a `Collection` that could be empty or contain many related models

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could access this from `Order` (since the dynamic property for this relationship is going to return a `Collection` we can use the `sum` method to help us out):

```
public function totalPrice()
{
    return $this->items->sum('AmountPaid');
}
```

Then call it on an `Order` instance.

```
$order->totalPrice();
```

If you are going to be retrieving numerous `Order` records and spinning through them to get these totals you will want to eager load the relationship to avoid the N+1.

```
$orders = Order::with('items')->....->get();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  return $this->items->sum('AmountPaid'); works brilliantly for me

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
$order = Order::with('items')->find(10);
$total = $order->totalPrice();
```

In your Order model, you need to write:

```
public function totalPrice()
{
    $total = 0;

    if (!empty($this->items)) {
        foreach($this->items as $item) {
            $total += $item->AmountPaid;
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Not the most elegant way, but might be worth looking into.

Comment: Nothing inelegant about this solution. This is the proper way to total up the items unless you want to resort to doing a SQL SUM. SQL would be in most cases since the DB can do the work, but depending on the caching setup, this could be very fast as well.